# nginx: Long filenames in directory listing

Tags: openbsd, nginx

Using nginx/1.4.1 with OpenBSD 5.4, 64bit:

[image]

How could we set nginx to show the full filename (or at least show more from the filename then the default) when using directory listing?

Googling around only gave me this:

```
http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,124400,167420#msg-167420
January 18, 2011 08:36PM
fagtron
I looked all over the net and wasn't able to find this answer anyway, so I looked into the nginx source files and it's very easy.

Simply modify the file located at [b]src/http/modules/ngx_http_autoindex_module.c[/b] and then compile.

Change these lines:

[b]#define NGX_HTTP_AUTOINDEX_PREALLOCATE 50

#define NGX_HTTP_AUTOINDEX_NAME_LEN 50[/b]

to whatever you want, such as:

[b]#define NGX_HTTP_AUTOINDEX_PREALLOCATE 100

#define NGX_HTTP_AUTOINDEX_NAME_LEN 100[/b]

And then compile and restart nginx. That's it !!!
```

**Question**: are there no other way then to recomplie it?

Comment: here is a manual, how to modify the nginx source: https://www.tecklyfe.com/nginx-display-full-filename-directory-listing/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [ngx_http_autoindex_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html) documentation, configuration of column width for autoindexed pages is not available. Compiling from the source would be the only way to make this change.

One alternative could be to use a scripting language (e.g. `php`, `ruby`, or `python`) to perform the directory listing for you.

Benefits include:

- fully customizable via CSS, JavaScript, etc
- fine control over file listing

Caveats:

- requires a [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) e.g. `php-fpm` or `passenger`
- requires more configuration

Comment: compiling did the trick

Comment: there is an answer with the parameters which should be changed for compiling - https://serverfault.com/questions/310532/stop-nginx-from-trimming-file-name-in-directory-list

Answer (score 8):

You can try fancyindex module with its fancyindex_name_length parameter to configure the filename length.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. note that `fancyindex_name_length` is not mentioned on the nginx page but is on the module's github page. note that this module is included in the `nginx-extras` package.

Answer (score 1):

Since there seems no way to achieve this than compiling nginx from the source this would be a **workaround**:

You can automatically create an index.html file in the current folder, that contains the whole path, with this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# scriptname: /usr/local/sbin/directory-long-index.sh
# 
# the directory_root without slash at the end:
WEB=/var/www/
#reacheable url from inside the server:
URL=http://localhost

P=$(pwd|sed "s|$WEB/||")
echo "download $URL/$P/ to index.html"
curl "$URL/$P/" -o index.html
sed -i 's|href="\(.*\)".*</a>|style="display:inline-block;min-width:500px" href="\1">\1</a>|' index.html
```

inside the folder just call:

```
source /usr/local/sbin/directory-long-index.sh
```

source: https://gist.github.com/rubo77/c7a9434eb104c00bf8772b2278284360

---

Another **workaround** would be to create a simple directory listing from scratch with

```
for i in *; do echo '<a href="'$i'">'$i'</a><br>'>>index.html; done
```

Comment: This isn't even remotely related to the user's question.

Comment: Sure it is. It is a workaround you can use if you don't want to compile nginx from source

Comment: Sorry about that; on first reading I failed to realize that this is intended as an a priori step to be run on the server.  Of course this will litter your directory structure with index.html files and needs to be re-run any time the underlying filesystem changes, but you are nevertheless correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
autoindex on;
autoindex_format json; # <- configure like this, your will get full name, FORMAT IN JSON
```

Document from [Module ngx_http_autoindex_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html#autoindex_format)

Answer (score 0):

You have the fullname in the link's href, you can do a bit of javascript to use it instead of the returned name